# How can I determine the pixel aspect ratio of a media file using AVFoundation on Lion?

Tags: objective-c, osx-lion, avfoundation

As part of a 64 bit Objective-C program I need to determine some parameters of media files on Lion.  For example for a video file, what is the pixel aspect ratio and is the video anamorphic?  I've been searching the AVFoundation API with no luck.  Any ideas on how to determine this information?

Thanks,

Barrie

Answer (score 0):

Although I am no AVFoundation expert, I would start looking at AVVideoWidthKey and AVVideoHeightKey dictionary keys in the video settings .. see http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html

Comment: pixel aspect ratio is not dependant on the width/height. however your link did lead me to find AVVideoPixelAspectRatioKey